# How to show canonical, title, description, twitter card & og tags in the view-source of the page (Server Side) in Angular

Tags: angular, meta-tags

I am adding canonical tag, title , description, OG tag and twitter card dynamically in my angular project. But the problem is it is not showing in the view-source of the page (Server Side).
But these tags are represented when viewing the page with Inspect Element (Client Side).

How can i show these also in view-source of the page.?

Comment: You need to use angular universal

Comment: I run into the same problem, but universal won't install for me, so I had to give up.